# Changing CSS of a div on click inside a for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, click, this, clip-path

I have a code to change a div's clip-path when it's clicked and I want the div's clip-path's to change in order of the array.

code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {
$('.branch').click(function(){
$(this).css('clip-path', positions[i]);
});
}
```

However this code will only run for the final iretation of the loop. I have seen some examples on how this would be fixed by putting the function outside the loop. But it doesn't work in my example. So please, if anyone knows how I can fix this, help me.

Comment: Do you want every `.branch` to change whenever *any* `.branch` is clicked, or what exactly is the logic you're looking for?

Comment: I want the branch div that is clicked to change it's clip-path to the one that is located in the `positions` array. So no matter wath div you click they will always tranform clip-path in order to build an image together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a persistent outside variable in order to keep track of how many times a click has occurred - set the css for the appropriate `positions` index, and increment the index:

```
let clickNumber = 0;
$('.branch').click(function(){
  if (clickNumber >= positions.length) return;
  $(this).css('clip-path', positions[clickNumber++]);
})
```

Comment: As much as this was helpful it seemed to assign each branch it's own pre-determined value from the array. I would like it to be that no matter what branch you click, it will always go to it's path in the array in order so that it looks like it's building itself, no matter of the order you click the branches. If you know of a way I could accomplish this please answer.

Comment: What you're looking for isn't clear, do you mean that on the `ith` click overall, that clicked branch will change to `positions[i]`, or what?

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much what I want it to be. No matter the order you click the divs they will reposition themself in an order to build an image. In theory I want to create an image out of randomly generated polygons floating around so when you click them they build an image together.